# Como verificar se um arquivo está corrompido em c#?

Tags: c#, arquivo

Como verificar se um arquivo está corrompido em c#?

Ex: Possuo um arquivo "xpto.txt" em um diretório e preciso verificar se esse arquivo não está corrompido.

Comment: Você tem algum [_checksum_](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soma_de_verifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o) do arquivo original, para então poder verificar e comparar?

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é conferindo o CRC. [Há uma biblioteca chamada DamienGKit que implementa o Crc32](https://github.com/damieng/DamienGKit/blob/master/CSharp/DamienG.Library/Security/Cryptography/Crc32.cs).

Exemplo de uso:

```
Crc32 crc32 = new Crc32();

String hash = String.Empty;

using (FileStream fs = File.Open("c:\\meuarquivo.txt", FileMode.Open))
  foreach (byte b in crc32.ComputeHash(fs)) hash += b.ToString("x2").ToLower();

Console.WriteLine("CRC-32 é {0}", hash);
```

[Tirei daqui](http://damieng.com/blog/2006/08/08/calculating_crc32_in_c_and_net). Este método só funciona se você tiver o CRC de um arquivo íntegro. Se forem diferentes (o CRC do original e da cópia) para uma mesma data de modificação, o arquivo está corrompido.

Outra forma é tentando abrir o arquivo como somente-leitura e verificar se essa abertura levanta alguma exceção, mas isso não necessariamente verifica se o arquivo está corrompido ou não: verifica apenas se ele pode ser lido ou não, que é outra coisa:

```
var fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\meuarquivo.txt");

try
{ 
  if (fi.IsReadOnly)
  {
    // Se entrar aqui, o arquivo está ok.
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Response.Write("Problema ao ler arquivo.");
}
```

[Este último tirei daqui](http://www.nullskull.com/q/10372753/how-to-check-that-file-is-corrupted.aspx).